# Route resource with route::group prefix laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I build a backend for admin in my application and create a route group for admin with a middleware Admin.

I place all my route resource for edit create delete in this group but when I try to navigate in this route with my nav menu

```
<a href="{{ action('CategorieController@index') }}">
```

I have an error for routing collection URL generator.

why I can't use the resource in a group with a prefix?
That's my code with route resource (not working)

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin' ,'middleware' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::resource('categories','CategorieController');

});
```

But that's work perfectly

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin' ,'middleware' => 'admin'], function() {     
Route::get('categories/allcat',['as'=>'categories.index','uses'=>'CategorieController@index']);
    Route::get('categories/ajout',['as'=>'categories.create','uses'=>'CategorieController@create']);
    Route::post('categories/ajout',['as'=>'categories.store','uses'=>'CategorieController@store']);
    Route::get('categories/editer/{id}',['as'=>'categories.edit','uses'=>'CategorieController@edit']);
    Route::patch('categories/editer/{id}',['as'=>'categories.update','uses'=>'CategorieController@update']);
    Route::delete('categories/destroy/{id}',['as'=>'categories.destroy','uses'=>'CategorieController@destroy']);
});
```

Just need a little help for understand why resource route does not work in a group with a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are using custom methods instead of Laravel's.

Try to keep original methods :

```
Route::get('categories/create'), ....
```

instead of :

```
Route::get('categories/ajout'), ....
```

Comment: yes but it's work with Route::get or Route::post but not with a Route::resource that's my problem

Comment: Route::resource uses default methods : create, store, update..etc , so it doesn't know their new names like ajout, editer

Comment: my route resource is with the default methods create store update ...  Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin' ,'middleware' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::resource('categories','CategorieController');

});

Comment: my second exemple work. But not with resource of my controller in my controller i have index create update .... so where is the problem don't look the second method i'm doing Route::get('categories/allcat',['as'=>'categories.index','uses'=>'CategorieController@index']);